# Building a REST API quickly from a Database model

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest

I've designed my database diagram(11 entites) for my prototype application.  I need to have an REST API on top of this that will allow me to build a prototype android tablet application that talks to it.

Considering this is only for prototype purposes. What would be the quickest way to get a API up and running that would allow me to get, put, delete etc..

Security at this point isn't an issue so even if all add edit delete were open that would be fine.

My initial idea is to build this with PHP and MySQL maybe using the Yii framework to help but I feel there might be something that might be faster for my purpose.

Any thoughts or recommendations or advice?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Recess framework yet? http://www.recessframework.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PATCH for updating a simple database field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995727/how-to-use-patch-for-updating-a-simple-database-field)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is worth looking into API rapid-prototyping tools like [Apify](https://github.com/apify/apify-library) ([tutorial](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2011/09/11/building-a-restful-web-api-with-php-and-apify/)) since you're starting from scratch. If you're planning to have both an API and a Web site accessing the same data, consider using one framework for both as it helps prevent duplicating logic. [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) are good examples of multipurpose frameworks that are suited for this type of development.

Answer (score 2):

If Python is an option, it is trivial to use a light-weight http framework to build a REST API that accesses a database.

Here's a snippet for a fully functioning http server using the itty framework:  https://github.com/toastdriven/itty/blob/master/examples/web_service.py and https://github.com/toastdriven/itty/blob/master/examples/posting_data.py

Comment: For PHP, see: https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api (Disclosure: I am the author.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this project which allows you to create an API REST in seconds.

https://github.com/GeekyTheory/Automatic-API-REST

### Features

1. Creation a powerful API REST of your MySQL Data Base in Seconds.
2. Management of the API in situ, it is not neccesary an extra data base.
3. Private tables and fields.
4. Custom queries.

### Installation

1. Clone the repo.

   git clone https://github.com/GeekyTheory/Automatic-API-REST/
2. Place it in your web folder `/var/www/YourWebPage/`
3. Open the file **config.php**  and complete all the fields with the server credencials.
4. Go to **domain.com/AutomaticaApiRest**