# Building a RESTful API based on a relational database

Tags: php, api, rest

I am trying to build a RESTful API.  I understand how RESTful API's work and I have developed a nice database structure and model for my api along with the code for detecting the request type and looping through each "node" individually.

> ## API Model
>
> ```
> Collection      Resource               Table
>
>
> associations    associations/AID       Associations
>
> Users           Users/UID              Users
>
> groups          groups/GID             Groups
>
> events          events/EID             Events 
>
> UID/events      UID/events/EID         Events_Map
>
> UID/groups      UID/groups/GID         Group_Map 
>
> GID/events      GID/events/EID         Group_Events
>
> AID/events      GID/events/EID         Association_Events
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### Relationships
>
> - association -> groups
> - association -> users
> - association -> events
> - user -> groups
> - user -> events
> - group -> users
> - group -> events

I am having trouble writing the php code for translating database resources into api resources.  I have read a lot of online tutorials for writing REST API's, but none of them address how to deal with nested data.  I would love to use a framework for this project, but it is for school.

---

In Summary how to I write code to handle complex api requests and generate the necessary database queries even if they include advanced functions such as join.

Comment: in summery writing the code is your job, when you have a problem with some actual code you have written, ask that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of me trying to explain my brains out on this, I found Apigee's blog to be the best resource for building APIs that are developer friendly. I've built 3 APIs now that are being relied upon in thousands of ecommerce websites using Apigee's stategy and the developer feedback has been excellent as I'm told its very intuitive. Credit to Apigee in a big way.

http://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar

Answer (score 0):

Example: When I need to look up a user using a UID the UID is passed to a stored procedure that selects the user based on that UID.

For my REST APIs I create objects that act as an intermediary between the API and the calls to the database

Also, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982897/building-a-rest-api-quickly-from-a-database-model?rq=1)